# Joomla: Permanently redirect from example.com/index.php/foo/bar to example.com/foo/bar (no index.php in URL)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

With this setup the page `/foo/bar` is accessible under the pretty URL `example.com/foo/bar` while the ugly URL `example.com/index.php/foo/bar` is still valid. What I need to achieve is a permanent redirection from `example.com/index.php/foo/bar` to `example.com/foo/bar`.

`RewriteRule .* index.php [R=301,L]` doesn't work.

`RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [R=301,L]` does the exact opposite, it redirects from `example.com/foo/bar` to `example.com/index.php/foo/bar`. Please help me out!

Comment: I don't know that anubhava has expertise in Joomla development.  While this problem (obviously) can be solved by non-Joomla developers, there are additional insights that you might receive by asking Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Have a read of this: https://joomlaseo.com/checklist/reroute-non-existing-url-s-with-301-redirects  If you are doing Joomla development, please join us at JSE.

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is not in line with the general referendum.

Comment: I also very much disagree with that odd justification for page closure.

Comment: @ThreeYearOld Once you and anubhava have joined JSE, I will ask moderators to migrate this page to that community.  This will allow Joomla experts to chime in with alternative, Joomla-specific techniques AND it will be a valuable contribution to our existing htaccess collection.

Comment: No, this question belongs here on SO, it is about rewrite rules i.e. `mod_rewrite` and is not Joomla specific. These rewrite rules can be used in any homegrown website without Joomla

Comment: That's true, but my point is that because this is specifically working with a Joomla environment -- there are additional techniques that can be used.  The question is in no way off-topic here.  My stance is that there will be greater benefit to the OP and Joomla researchers by migrating it there.  Stack Overflow has no shortage of htaccess questions, so this community will not be negatively affected in any fashion by the migration.

Comment: Better than moving questions between platforms, it would be much better to add a section of useful links of Joomla questions related to rewrite rules on Joomla forum. As I am proposing it, I would myself do that in case you don't have any objections (since I new user there)

Comment: @mickmackusa To let my question migrate to JSE? No, thank you!

Comment: Why would you not like your Joomla-related question to JSE? @Three  What harm is there in putting Joomla-related questions on JSE?  How can I possibly grow the dedicated community if it has to share its questions with Stack Overflow?   See my struggle: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351032/352329

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend writing this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove index.php from / OR any /dir
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# redirect rule to remove /index.php/ from start
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/.*) $1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In the new rule, we match a pattern using regex `^index\.php(/.*)` which matches a URI that starts with `/index.php/` followed by zero or more of any characters. `(/.*)` is our match and the capture group after `/index.php` which is used as back-reference i.e. `$1` (string that we've captured in group #1) in target to get a URI after `/index.php` as desired.

**References:**

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Comment: That's why I included a reference links in the answer. `mod_rewrite` rules have this DSL. `RewriteRule <pattern> <action/target> <flags>`. So target is something that we are redirecting/rewriting to.

Comment: What do I need to change to additionally have `example.com/index.php` redirected to `example.com`?

Comment: `DSL` = `domain-specific language`?

Comment: Is `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` actually more efficient than `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`?

Comment: 1. Yes `DSL = domain-specific language`. 2. Yes `RewriteRule ^` is slightly more efficient than `RewriteRule .*`. I am adding a rule to redirect `example.com/index.php` to `example.com/`

Comment: The rule to redirect `example.com/index.php` to `example.com/` affects the Joomla backend, it locks you out of it. Why is that?

Comment: @ThreeYearOld: I am not a Joomla expert but you can try adding a `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/` condition before that rule. If you still have an issue please feel free to ask a new question with Joomla tag

Comment: How does this condition provide a remedy? Does it even still match `example.com/index.php`? Thank you!

Comment: Yes that new condition matches `/index.php/anything`

Comment: But it doesn't match `example.com/index.php` (without trailing slash), does it?

Comment: The rule I have in my answer below `# remove index.php from / OR any /dir` removed `/index.php` from any path and there should not be any trailing slash after `index.php`. What I have in comments due to all the extended discussion

Comment: You mean "above" and not "below", don't you? Yes, the rule in your answer matches `example.com/index.php`, but with the condition in your comment (`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/`) it doesn't, does it?